# Android onTrackballEvent and Click

Tags: android

I want to capture onClick events for the trackball on a HTC Hero. This event is firing and I can get the direction of motion of the trackball:

```
@Override
public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent event) {

}
```

How do I find out if the event was a click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overriding `onKeyDown()`, watching for the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER` event.